# How to sum amounts in column given specific criteria in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with two columns. A (for example) has the values 1 2 2 3 4 4 5 and B has 1.2 4.3 3 2 5 4.5 7.

How do I total the amounts in column B given that the cell to its left equals 2? In this case it should return (4.3 + 3 = 7.3).

Sorry, I wish I knew how to draw a sample table here but I don't know how. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That worked. Although I don't know why you didn't make that an answer

Comment: Well thanks either way, I remember learning that now but completely forgot.

Comment: @pnuts Why not explain the function a bit? It's a valid answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUMIF(A:A,2,B:B)
```

seems to have met the bill. The [SUMIF](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumif.php) syntax is:

> SUMIF( range, criteria, [sum_range] )

where the sum_range is shown as optional since the default is to sum the range.

This [page regarding formatting of a sample table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) may be of interest.

Comment: That link is super helpful. Bookmarked.